# Uncaught Error: You are loading the CommonJS build of React Router on a page that is already running the ES modules build, so things won't work right

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying using this BrowserRoute in my App.js , it is giving me the following error since a long time , unable to resolve this please help me with this.I have installed react-router-dom@5
Here is my code for App.js

```
import react from 'react'
import Homepage from "./Pages/Homepage"
import ChatPage from "./Pages/ChatPage"
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom/cjs/react-router-dom.min';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route exact path = "/" component = {Homepage}/>
        <Route exact path = "/chats" component = {ChatPage}/>
      </BrowserRouter>
      
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import { Route, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';`